# Copy Json Flat file from local to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

```
package com.Main;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        //Source file in the local file system
        String localSrc = args[0];

        //Destination file in HDFS
        String dst = args[1];

        //Input stream for the file in local file system to be written to HDFS
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localSrc));

        //Get configimport org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;uration of Hadoop system
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        System.out.println("Connecting to -- "+conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));

        //Destination file in HDFS
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);
        OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(dst)); 

        //Copy file from local to HDFS
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);

        System.out.println(dst + " copied to HDFS");
    }

}
```

AM getting following error message "**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.Main.Main.main(Main.java:22)**"

I have Json file in my local , have to move that in HDFS
**Ex:**
{"Del":"Ef77xvP","time":1509073785106},
{"Del":"2YXsF7r","time":1509073795109}

Comment: how are you running this? Are you providing arguments to the JAR at runtime?

Comment: `hdfs dfs -put file.json`... It isn't that hard

Answer (score 0):

Specify command line arguments to your program. You code snippet expects first argument to be source and next arguments to be destination.
For more details refer to [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)

Comment: Specify command line arguments to your program --> Am not getting this, Can you please explain briefly.

Comment: eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222153/eclipse-how-we-take-arguments-for-main-when-run
intellij: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951846/run-programme-from-intellij-with-command-line-file-input